# uninstall a theme programmaticlly

Tags: functions, child-theme, uninstallation

I'm working on a plugin that create, install, switch between child themes.

But I have a problem that my plugin creates just 2 or 3 child themes ( Is there any limit in creating child themes?).

So I'm looking for a way to delete a child theme programmatically by codes before throwing my function that create the other theme.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

1. The limit of the child theme is not a border from WordPress, maybe your webspace.
2. If you remove the directory of a child theme, include all files, if is deleted. For the delete of the folder use [`rmdir()`](https://github.com/WordPress/WordPress/blob/master/wp-admin/includes/class-wp-filesystem-direct.php#L451).
   The method `rmdir()` is part of the classes that extend `WP_Filesystem_Base`, like `WP_Filesystem_Direct` and accordingly the `rmdir()` method in that class. Take a look at the the `wp-admin/includes` directory to inspect the other classes yourself.

Comment: I tried it inside my function like that but it didn't delete the directory.
$parent_dirone = $this->theme->get_stylesheet_directory();
$child_dirone = $parent_dirone . '-child-2';
rmdir($child_dirone, $recursive = false);
Is that the correct way.

Comment: I think you should use `$recursive = false`. The function use `delete()` of this class, that only delete files. But it checks for a dir, if is $recursive is false - `if ( ! $recursive && $this->is_dir($file) ) return @rmdir($file);` Have you try, that the rights to delete are correctly?